selling on settlement date
In my IRA account, if I buy a stock on Monday with my settled cash, can I sell it anytime after purchasing, even 1 minute or, I have to wait 2 business days, so it means Wednesday? Sorry for simple question I checked and asked but want to make sure. Thanks

Yes you can sell your stock at any time after your purchase.  In a cash account in the USA, settlement is currently two days (T+2).  You can buy another stock with unsettled funds but you cannot selling the new stock before the sale of the first stock is settled - this would be a Good Faith Violation.
Last year, the Securities and Exchange Commission adopted amendments shortening settlement time.  As of May 28, 2024 the standard settlement cycle for most broker-dealer transactions will be reduced from T+2 to T+1 subject to certain exceptions.  T+1 will apply to the same securities transactions covered by the T+2 settlement cycle (stocks, bonds, municipal securities, exchange-traded funds, certain mutual funds, and limited partnerships).

what confused me actually was, in my account when i look at my transaction history, for a stock that I bought on say april 2nd, it says settlement date april 4th. I called and asked them, and they told me yes the earliest I can sell the stock is 4/4. That is what confused me.

If you bought the stock with settled funds then your broker has misinformed you.

Yes you can sell it immediately after, you just might not be able to use the proceeds for something else until the new trade settles.  Settlement only affects your ability to use cash from transactions; it does not prevent you from selling securities you bought.

what confused me actually was, in my account when i look at my transaction history, for a stock that I bought on say april 2nd, it says settlement date april 4th. I called and asked them, and they told me yes the earliest I can sell the stock is 4/4. That is what confused me.

Hmm maybe some brokers are more strict - I can buy stock and sell it the same day, but if I sell it, I can't use the proceeds to buy new stock until it settles.

may be it is more strict because it is a traditional ira account? anyway so if i go by what my broker tells me, i can sell it on settlement date of april 4th - but first i thought it should be the 5th because it is confusing when something settles on a certain day and you can sell it the same day , i mean what if you sell it at an earlier hour than it settles etc... may be i am thinking too much.

Brokers cannot be more strict about when you can sell a stock.  Nor are settlement and saleable rules different if it's an IRA account.
